# When i JsonConvert.DeserializeObject its just stops working in asp.net core

Tags: json, firebase, asp.net-core, deserialization

I'm trying to `DeserializeObject` my data to `User` class and when i do that, the method acts like nothing happend and finishing himself.
[image]
[image]

And that's my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserSurname { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(50), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string UserEMail { get; set; }
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public bool UserIsActive { get; set; }
    public bool UserIsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Here it's my code :

```
firebaseClient = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(firebaseConfig);
FirebaseResponse response = firebaseClient.Get("Users/");
User data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response.Body);//That's the point where i get the problem.
```

I'm working with Firebase,FireSharp and Asp.Net Core 5.0

Comment: It looks like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` throws an exception. My guess is it's because your `UserId` is set to `int` but the one returned is a `string`.

Comment: you are so right! thank you @KirkLarkin